# Causes of play console errors java.lang.VerifyError and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (stacktrace added)

Tags: java, android, crash, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app That I have been trying to get on the play store and incorporate ads... which was a success. The app was finished and working on my test device and then I uploaded it to the play store.

When I download it from the playstore onto the same device though, it crashes with an error that the app has stopped working.

On the console in the crash overview I'm getting these two errors:

```
java.lang.VerifyError
com.boxfanspak.boxy.MainActivity.onCreate
```

with stacktrace:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: 
at java.lang.Class.classForName (Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:454)
at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:379)
at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.instantiatePlugin 
(PluginManager.java:564)
at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin 
(PluginManager.java:183)
at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.startupPlugins 
(PluginManager.java:108)
at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.init (PluginManager.java:96)
at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.init 
(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:119)
at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init (CordovaActivity.java:152)
at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl 
(CordovaActivity.java:227)
at com.boxfanspak.boxy.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:39)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8207)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8191)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate 
(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
(ActivityThread.java:3808)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity 
(ActivityThread.java:4011)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute 
(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks 
(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute 
(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage 
(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

and

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
```

with stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
(ActivityThread.java:3726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity 
(ActivityThread.java:4011)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute 
(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks 
(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute 
(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass 
(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity 
(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity 
(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1253)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
(ActivityThread.java:3714)
```

I really don't know anything about java so I'm really lost even when researching this issue. I'm not even sure where to begin here, if anyone can help I really appreciate it.

I didn't write my project in Java and am doing my best to learn what needs done, at this time I believe I need to  update dependencies to a version built using a JDK version that matches the JDK version used to build the application which is JDK 11 I believe? I am unsure of how to do this and could be completely off here.